# Spring Security SuccessHandler error with forward

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I keep getting a Http 400 error when I try an Http POST or Http PUT with using a custom SuccessHandler. Specifically the error occurs, after I forward the request. I forward the request as follows:

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        String context = request.getContextPath();
        String fullURL = request.getRequestURI();
        String url = fullURL.substring(fullURL.indexOf(context)
                + context.length());
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).include(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

Any of my other calls that do not include a RequestBody do not produce a Http 400 error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didn't understand the `include` and `forward` methods for a RequestDispatcher. By removing `request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);` I got it to work. An explanation of why can be found at: http://www.theserverside.com/tip/Include-vs-Forward-of-the-Servlet-RequestDispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

As the request dispatcher works for servlets on the same server, try request.getRequestDispatcher(conetext)... where "context" is the relative target of your foreward on your server i.e. /webapp/login
See i.e.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29
- http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=206736

Comment: request.getRequestDispatcher(path) --> "path" is the path to the resource on your server. So if you receive your request on `http://www.example.com/webapp/login` and "path" is "index.jsp", it's relative and the resulting target is `http://www.example.com/webapp/login/index.jsp`. If "path" is /index.jsp, the path is absolute and targets `http://www.example.com/webapp/index.jsp`

Comment: This would not forward me to the correct place in my webapp, and would only forward me to the index

Comment: As far as i understand, you wan't to foreward to where the request initialy was targeted to. Am i right?

Comment: In my case, the success handler is for api key authentication. So the success handler is for when the api key is correct, so I would want to forward them to their original destination

Comment: My try would be to get the path (absolute to the servlet) and pass that to request.getRequestDispatcher. So if the initialy requested URL was `http://example.com/webapp/login`, trim the server and servlet part and get /login as absolute, initialy requested path.

Comment: Sorry, i think my last comment was not correct. --> trim the server path and get the path absolute to the server. So the absolute path will be /webapp/login where webapp is the servlet. Here is a nice post on that http://addictedtojava.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/requestdispatcher-and-its-working-with.html